# Pycharm autocomplete freezes the IDE

Tags: pycharm

When I am typing in pycharm 3 (running on macbook air) and I am typing Javascript, the IDE freezes temporarily to populate autocomplete.

This has become very annoying off late and is happening all the time. It even makes me loose focus. Is there something I can do to make it run faster?